# ¿Cómo hacer un recuento con filtro?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

Sé como hacer un count sobre los elementos de un array:

```
inputs = ['truc','truc','machin','bidule']
c = []
for y in set(inputs):
    count = 0
    for x in inputs:
        if x ==y:
             count+=1
    c.append({y:count})
print(c)
```

Me gustaria saber como hacerlo utilisando `filter`. Ya estoy teniendo problemas para conseguir los elementos que ya están en el cuadro:

```
mismos = filter(lambda x: x==x, inputs)
```

Comment: Hola, la utilidad de filter como su nombre indica es filtrar items de un iterable usando un callable que retorne un boleano paara cada item. ¿Qué salida esperas exactamente? ¿Quieres contar o filtrar items que cumplan cierta característica? Si solo buscas un método más eficiente para contar, filter no es la solución.

Comment: Hola @FJSevilla, Sí, el objetivo final era crear una forma más eficiente de contar. Pero también para aprender a usar bien `filter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Algunas notas sobre tu implementación

Hay algunos puntos críticos que hacen ineficiente tu método para contar elementos en la lista.

Usas `set` para eliminar  duplicados, lo cual es un método muy eficiente, el mejor si no nos importa el orden y los items son "hashables" de hecho. El problema es que iteras  en el peor de los casos `len(inputs) + 1` veces sobre la lista `inputs` al completo.

A eso hay que sumar la sobrecarga de la llamada a  `list.append`.

Usar un diccionario en vez de `set` + `list` nos resuelve el problema, por un lado mantenemos la eficiencia de `set` por el uso de tablas hash y por otro solo tenemos que **iterar una sola vez** sobre la lista.

```
def counter(iterable):
    count_dict = {}
    for item in iterable:
        try:
            count_dict[item] += 1
        except KeyError:
            count_dict[item] = 1
    return [{item: count} for item, count in count_dict.items()]
```

o si no te gusta el manejo de excepciones:

```
def counter(iterable):
    count_dict = {}
    for item in iterable:
        count_dict[item] = count_dict.get(item, 0) + 1
    return [{item: count} for item, count in count_dict.items()]
```

> ```
> >>> inputs = ['truc','truc','machin','bidule']
> >>> cont = counter(inputs)
> >>> cont
> [{'truc': 2}, {'machin': 1}, {'bidule': 1}]
> ```

`collections.defaultdict` sería útil, pero ya que importamos algo, no reinventemos la rueda:

---

### `collections.Counter`

Por lo general, la forma más eficiente de contar items en un iterable cualquiera siempre que sean hashables es usar `collections.Counter`. Si quieres una salida igual que la tuya basta con usar una lista por compresión e iterar sobre la vista items del diccionario igual que hacemos arriba.

```
import collections


inputs = ['truc','truc','machin','bidule']
cont = [{item: cont} for item,  cont in collections.Counter(inputs).items()]
```

> ```
> >>> cont
> [{'truc': 2}, {'machin': 1}, {'bidule': 1}]
> ```

El la idea básica detrás de `Counter` es muy similar al explicado arriba, aunque la parte encargada de contar está optimizada a mediante una función en C.

---

### `filter`

`filter` es una función que entra dentro del soporte básico que da Python a la programación funcional junto a `map`, `functools.reduce`, `itertools.takewhile`, `itertools.filterfalse` e `itertool.dropwhile`. Permite fitrar un iterable cualquiera aplicando una función o cualquier otro callable que toma como argumento cada item y retorna siempre `True` o `False`. En Python 3 retorna un iterador.

Por ejemplo, imaginemos que queremos quedarnos solo con los items que tienen una "u" de tu lista:

```
tienen_u = list(filter(lambda item: "u" in item.lower(), inputs))
```

> ```
> >>> tienen_u
> ['truc', 'truc', 'bidule']
> ```

es realmente un reemplazo a un ciclo `for` con un condicional, de hecho otra forma de hacer lo mismo es:

```
tienen_u = [item for item in inputs if "u" in item.lower()]
```

que en este caso es más concisa incluso, con rendimiento similar y muchos la prefieren de hecho, incluido seguramente Guido (BDFL), que se conoce por no apreciar mucho la programación funcional... :)

---

### Filtrar y contar

Obviamente podemos unir ambas cosas:

```
def filter_counter(function, iterable):
    count_dict = {}
    for input in filter(function, iterable):
        try:
            count_dict[input] += 1
        except KeyError:
            count_dict[input] = 1
    return [{item: count} for item, count in count_dict.items()]
```

> ```
> >>> inputs = ['truc','truc','machin','bidule']
> >>> cont = filter_counter(lambda item: "u" in item.lower(), inputs)
> >>> cont
> [{'truc': 2}, {'bidule': 1}]
> ```

o usando `collections.Counter`:

```
import collections


inputs = ['truc','truc','machin','bidule']

filtro = filter(lambda item: "u" in item.lower(), inputs)
cont = [{item: cont} for item, cont in collections.Counter(filtro).items()]
```

> ```
> >>> cont
> [{'truc': 2}, {'bidule': 1}]
> ```

dónde como se ha comentado, `filter` pude ser substituido por una expresión generadora con un condicional:

```
import collections


inputs = ['truc','truc','machin','bidule']

filtro = (item for item in inputs if "u" in item.lower())
cont = [{item: cont} for item, cont in collections.Counter(filtro).items()]
```